# Proving Properties Of Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

> Prove the following:
>
> 1. $$\overline{(\frac{z_1}{z_2})}=\frac{\overline{z_1}}{\overline{z_2}}$$
>
> 2.$$\overline{z_1\cdot z_2\cdot\cdot\cdot z_n}=\overline{z_1}\cdot \overline{z_2}\cdot \cdot \cdot\overline{z_n}$$
>
> 3. $$z+z^2+...+z^n=\frac{z-z^{n+1}}{1-z}$$

1.$$\overline{(\frac{z_1}{z_2})}=\overline{(\frac{x_1+y_1i}{x_2+y_2i})}=\overline{(\frac{x_1+y_1i}{x_2+y_2i})}\cdot \frac{x_2-y_2i}{x_2-y_2i}=\overline{\frac{x_1x_2+y_1y_2-(x_1y_2+y_2x_2)i}{x_2^2+y_2^2}}=\frac{x_1x_2+y_1y_2+x_1y_2i+y_2x_2i}{x_2^2+y_2^2}$$ How should I continue

2. In induction for n=2:  $$\overline{z_1\cdot z_2}=\overline{z_1}\cdot \overline{\cdot z_2}$$
   assume for n: $$\overline{z_1\cdot z_2\cdot\cdot\cdot z_n}=\overline{z_1}\cdot \overline{z_2}\cdot \cdot \cdot\overline{z_n}$$
   Prove for n+1:  $$\overline{z_1\cdot z_2\cdot\cdot\cdot z_{n}\cdot z_{n+1}}=\overline{z_1\cdot z_2\cdot\cdot\cdot z_{n}}\cdot\overline{\cdot z_{n+1}}=\overline{z_1}\cdot \overline{z_2}\cdot\cdot\cdot \overline{z_{n}}\cdot \overline{z_{n+1}}$$
3. $$S_{n}=\frac{a_1\cdot (q^n-1)}{q-1}$$
   $$S_{n}=\frac{z\cdot (z^n-1)}{z-1}$$
   $$S_{n}=\frac{(z^{n+1}-z)}{z-1}=\frac{-(z-z^{n+1})}{-(1-z)}=\frac{z-z^{n+1}}{1-z}$$

Are 2 and  3 correct?

Comment: Hint: prove first that $\,\overline{ab}=\bar a \bar b\,$, then **2** follows by induction, and for **1** what's left to prove is that $\,\overline{1 / z}=1 / \bar z\,$.

Comment: For 1., you need to somehow compare it to $\frac{\bar z_1}{\bar z_2}$, so why not insert $x+iy$ in there and see what you get?

Comment: 2) "for n=2:
z1⋅z2¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯=z1¯¯¯¯¯⋅⋅z2¯¯¯¯¯¯"  Um... okay, go ahead.  Prove that .  Saying it, isn't proving it.

Comment: "How should I continue" .  Stop.  Then show that $\frac {\overline z_1}{\overline z_2}$ equals the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.  I'd start by proving $\overline z *\overline w = \overline {z*w}$ which is easy to show.

Let $z = a+bi$ and $w= c+di$ then

$\overline z * \overline w = (a-bi)(c-di) = (ac - bd) -(bc + ad)i $.

$\overline {z*w}= \overline {(a+bi)(c+di)}  = \overline {(ac - bd) +(bc + ad)i}= (ac - bd) -(bc + ad)i $.

Then I guess for 1) we also have to show $\frac 1{\overline z} = \overline {\frac 1z}$ which is $\frac {1}{\overline z} = \frac 1 {a-bi} = \frac {a+bi}{a^2 + b^2}$ while $\overline {\frac {1}{z}} = \overline {\frac {1}{a+bi}} = \overline{\frac {a - bi}{a^2 + b^2}} = \frac {a+bi}{a^2 + b^2}$.

Then all follow immediately:

1) $\overline {\frac{z_1}{z_2}}= \overline {z_1}*\overline {\frac 1{z_2}} = \overline {z_1}*\frac 1{\overline {z_2}}=\frac {\overline {z_1}}{\overline {z_2}}$.

2) is just induction $\overline {{z_1}*{z_2}*...*{z_n}} = \overline {{z_1}*{z_2}*...}*\overline{{z_n}}= ...+\overline{z_1}*\overline{z_2} *....*\overline {z_n}$

I guess 3) is different. $( z + z^2 + .... + z^n)(1-z) = (z - z^2) + (z^2 - z^3) + ..... + (z^n - z^{n+1}) = z + (-z^2 + z^2) + ..... + (-z^n + z^n) - z^{n+1} = z -z^{n+1}$.

So if $z \ne 1$ then $z + z^2 + .... + z^n = \frac {z- z^{n+1}}{1 - z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Polar representation $z=|z|e^{i\phi}$ is useful for 1. and 2.

1. $$
   \overline{ \left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)}=\overline{\left(\frac{|z_1|e^{i\phi_1}}{|z_2|e^{i\phi_2}}\right)}=\overline{\frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}e^{i(\phi_1-\phi_2)}}=\frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}e^{i(-\phi_1+\phi_2)}=\frac{|z_1|e^{-i\phi_1}}{|z_2|e^{-i\phi_2}}\\=\frac{\overline{z_1}}{\overline{z_2}}$$

2.

$$\begin{align}
\overline {z_1·z_2···z_n} &= \overline {|z_1|e^{i\phi_1}|z_2|e^{i\phi_2}···|z_n|e^{i\phi_n}}\\
&= \overline {|z_1||z_2|···|z_n|e^{i\phi_1}e^{i\phi_2}···e^{i\phi_n}}\\
&= \overline {|z_1||z_2|···|z_n|e^{i(\phi_1+\phi_2+...+\phi_n)}}\\
&= {|z_1||z_2|···|z_n|e^{-i(\phi_1+\phi_2+...+\phi_n)}}\\
&= |z_1||z_2|···|z_n|e^{-i\phi_1}e^{-i\phi_2}···e^{-i\phi_n}\\
&= |z_1|e^{-i\phi_1}|z_2|e^{-i\phi_2}···|z_n|e^{-i\phi_n}= \overline {z_1}·\overline{z_2}···\overline{z_n}
\end{align}$$